# Is there a small web server alternative to Apache which only serves files?

Tags: linux, http, debian, file-server

I've written a few scripts in Batch and Bash in the past which download a file directly from my web server.

I don't want to use or pay for an external hosting service for this, and I need the files to be accessible from a url. For example I need it to be directly downloadable from "http://myserver.uk.to/file.zip".

For a while I've used Apache to accomplish this, and just accessing it how I have above.

I've recently needed to do this again, and now that I own a new server machine, I don't want to have to reconfigure Apache again, and I'm aiming to keep the contents of the server "clean and tidy".

I'm wondering, since the only thing I need to do is distribute a file over HTTP, is there a more simple piece of software I can install which doesn't require too much configuring, and which doesn't come with all the extra features attached to it like Apache does?

I'm using Debian.

Thanks!

Comment: [This (off-topic) StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050851/best-lightweight-web-server-only-static-content-for-windows) might give you some ideas. Since it's targetting Windows, it's not an _answer_ for you, but it suggests some possible directions to explore.

Comment: I've not tried one of those, but maybe take a look at mini-httpd (`apt show mini-httpd`) and the even smaller micro-httpd (`apt show micro-httpd`)?

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/LaMp might make it easier, or https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mariadb-php-lamp-stack-on-debian-11  I think you just have to bite the bullet. Or, consider https://wiki.debian.org/Samba/ServerSimple - which you still have to configure. Do you have a backup of your old configuration (why not?)